# Jest expect object property value not to be object

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

I have an array of 'flat' objects, i.e. properties whose values are either a string, number, null etc.

```
let myArray = [
    {
        prop1: 'string'
        prop2: 123
    },
    {
        prop1: 'string'
        prop2: 123
    },
]
```

In this case I don't care what the actual property keys are and ideally I don't want to know what they are in advance, i just want to check the property values are objects.

The following would fail for example

```
let myArray = [
    {
        prop1: 'string'
        prop2: 123
    },
    {
        prop1: 'string'
        prop2: {
            prop3: true
        }
    },
]
```

How can I write this in a jest test?

```
expect(myArray).toEqual(
    expect.arrayContaining([
        expect.toBeObject()
        expect.objectValues.not.toBeObject    // What do I actually put here
    ])
);
```

I am using jest extended.

Answer (score 1):

The requirements for the object are specific enough to be asserted explicitly. Jest Extended has `toSatisfyAll` to assert all array elements:

```
let hasPrimitiveVals = obj => (
  Object.values(obj).every(val => (
    val === null || !['object', 'function'].includes(typeof val)
  ))
);

expect(myArray).toEqual(Array(myArray.length).fill(expect.any(Object));
expect(myArray).toSatisfyAll(hasPrimitiveVals);
```

It's also possible to do this with Jest asymmetric matcher alone:

```
expect(myArray).toEqual(Array(myArray.length).fill({ asymmetricMatch: hasPrimitiveVals }));
```

None of them will specify which element failed the expectation. If more specific error is needed on fail, this is the case for custom matcher.